# What is the limit distribution of $\bar X^{-1}$ when $\mathbb E X_k = 0$?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d. with $\mathbb E X_1 = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_1) = \sigma^2 \in (0, \infty)$. Denote $\bar X(n) = n^{-1}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$. What is the limit distribution of $\bar X(n)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{X}(n)^{-1}$ is undefined when $\overline{X}(n) = 0$, but let's suppose this has probability $0$ (e.g. if $X_k$ are continuous).

By the Weak Law of Large Numbers, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb P(|\overline{X}(n)|) < \epsilon) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.  Thus $\mathbb P(|\overline{X}(n)^{-1}| \ge \epsilon^{-1}) \to 1$.  There is no limiting distribution.